# No-code sandboxed solutions (NCSS) and Sharepoint 2013 App Model

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

Microsoft recently [clarified](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions.aspx) its stand on Sandbox solutions.

*"While developing sandboxed solutions that contain only declarative markup and JavaScript -- which we call no-code sandboxed solutions (NCSS) -- is still viable, we have deprecated the use of custom managed code within the sandboxed solution."*

Both NCSS(no-code sandboxed solutions) and app model can have only declarative markup and Javascript files. Is it safe to say that NCSS won't be of much value for a SharePoint 2013 farm configured for apps already? Are there any scenarios where you would prefer NCSS over app model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily deploy assets to the host web via NCSS. This requires custom code and full control permissions for an app, not to mention the creation and maintenance of an app web just for the sole purpose of copying files to the host web upon activation of the app.